# CSS: Hover over a link but image is not displayed

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, hover

In practice, when I hover these links, all of them turn green as the first hover selector get executed fine. However, for the last link "cde", I call another hover selector to display an image, it does not work.

*What I have tried:*

- Set **original** opacity = 0  -- **hover** opacity  = 1  --> does not work
- Set **original** display = none -- **hover** display = block --> does not work

**Question: Is there any way to get an image to appear with the texts turn green?**

Thank you so much in advance for your help. Highly appreciate!

```css
 
.work-abcde a:hover{
  color: #61c261;
  }

  .cde-pic{
  position: relative;
  width: -100px;
  top: -100px;
  float: right;
  visibility: hidden;
  }

.cde:hover .cde-pic {
  position: relative;
  left: -20px;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="work-abcde">
<ul>
<li><h3>abc bcd cde</h3></li>
<li><h4><a class="abc" href="www.abc.com" rel="nofollow"> abc</a> </h4></li>
<li><h4><a class="bcd" href="www.bcd.com" rel="nofollow"> bcd </a> </h4></li>
<li><h4><a class="cde" href="www.cde.com" rel="nofollow"> cde</a> </h4> </li>
<div class="cde-pic"><img src="./Resources/cde.png" ></div>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The HTML has an error: the div is not inside a <li>. Also, you never change the width on hover; maybe that's the problem. How large is the picture?

Comment: @Mr Lister Thank you so much for your comment. Yes! I moved the <div> inside the <li> and follow the solutions provided below and boom! it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is **css selector can't target parent in pure CSS**, you can target sibling or child but not the parent (pure CSS).

`A CSS selector can contain more than one simple selector. Between the simple selectors, we can include a combinator.`

#### There are four different combinators in CSS3:

```
descendant selector (space)
child selector (>)
adjacent sibling selector (+)
general sibling selector (~)
```

For more about child/sibling selector you could read more here (2 mins of reading) https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp

#### Solution 1:

`<li>` and `<div>` are sibling. so use `li` hover instead of class `cde`, then you can target the `cde-pic` class:

```
li:hover ~ .cde-pic {
  position: relative;
  left: -20px;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```css
.work-abcde a:hover {
  color: #61c261;
}

.cde-pic {
  position: relative;
  width: -100px;
  top: -100px;
  float: right;
  visibility: hidden;
}

li:hover + .cde-pic {
  position: relative;
  left: -20px;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="work-abcde">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h3>abc bcd cde</h3>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h4><a class="abc" href="www.abc.com" rel="nofollow"> abc</a> </h4>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h4><a class="bcd" href="www.bcd.com" rel="nofollow"> bcd </a> </h4>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h4><a class="cde" href="www.cde.com" rel="nofollow"> cde </a> </h4>
    </li>
    <div class="cde-pic">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff">
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

#### Solution 2:

Move `<div>` into `<li>`, so they become sibling (`cde` and `cde-pic`).

```css
.work-abcde a:hover {
  color: #61c261;
}

.cde-pic {
  position: relative;
  width: -100px;
  top: -100px;
  float: right;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.cde:hover + .cde-pic {
  position: relative;
  left: -20px;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="work-abcde">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h3>abc bcd cde</h3>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h4><a class="abc" href="www.abc.com" rel="nofollow"> abc</a> </h4>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h4><a class="bcd" href="www.bcd.com" rel="nofollow"> bcd </a> </h4>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h4>
        <a class="cde" href="www.cde.com" rel="nofollow"> cde </a>
        <div class="cde-pic">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff">
        </div>
      </h4>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @kmartin thanks, you are right. I should use `+` then it will target the next `cde-pic` class.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear explanation, additional source, and solutions.

Answer (score 1):

This selector which you use...

```
.cde:hover .cde-pic { ... }
```

...cannot work, since `.cde-pic` is *not*  a child element of `.cde`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```css
.work-abcde a:hover{
  color: #61c261;
  }

  .cde-pic{
  position: relative;
  top: -100px;
  float: right;
  display:none;
  }

.cde:hover:after {
  content: url("//images.google.com/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png"); /* no need for qoutes */
   position: relative;
  display:block;
  left: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="work-abcde">
<ul>
<li><h3>abc bcd cde</h3></li>
<li><h4><a class="abc" href="www.abc.com" rel="nofollow"> abc</a> </h4></li>
<li><h4><a class="bcd" href="www.bcd.com" rel="nofollow"> bcd </a> </h4></li>
<li><h4><a class="cde" href="www.cde.com" rel="nofollow"> cde</a> </h4> </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with JS...
Here is the code:

```js
function chbg(vis) {
    document.getElementById('cde').style.visibility = vis
}
```

```css
.work-abcde a:hover {
  color: #61c261;
}

.cde-pic {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.cde:hover .cde-pic {
  position: relative;
  left: -20px;
  visibility: visible;
}

a:hover > .cde-pic {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="work-abcde">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h3>abc bcd cde</h3>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h4><a onmouseover="chbg('visible')" onmouseout="chbg('hidden')"  class="abc" href="www.abc.com" rel="nofollow"> abc</a> </h4>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h4><a onmouseover="chbg('visible')" onmouseout="chbg('hidden')" class="bcd" href="www.bcd.com" rel="nofollow"> bcd </a> </h4>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h4><a onmouseover="chbg('visible')" onmouseout="chbg('hidden')" class="cde" href="www.cde.com" rel="nofollow"> cde</a> </h4>
    </li>
    <div class="cde-pic" id="cde"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/"></div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: JavaScript is overkill in this case.

Comment: Thank you very much, it surely helps!